# MeshPhongMaterial in Three.js 62 and 67

Tags: three.js

In the 62 version of Three.js library fine brilliant material. I can't pick up parameters for the same plausible gloss in the 67 version. 
How to be? What need to be taken parameters for a material?
Example [here](http://neftek.legko.ufanet.ru/MyWebGL/extrude/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The material "Shininess" on each of them is different. Your r67 material has a shininess of 6 and your r62 material has a shininess of 50

Comment: Yes, I know. If r67 material has a shininess of 50 will be even worse.